# Identify the hash methods (md5, sha1) given only hashed string

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, hash

I am asked to setup the application on [this repository](https://github.com/salman-/ignit-QA), which works with `MySql` and `jsp`, and run a `selenium` test against some functionalities. The file `bank.sql` is the schema of the database.

But, I believe the application is broken because, I am not provided the credential to log into the system. The query such as:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `enabled`) VALUES
('Jake', 'e2a79383c1347633461eb9fb56cf4972a0155919', 1),
('Maria', '3e182b1ea9376483a38614d916a0b666ef531b6d', 1),
('Mike', 'd6ac022931a66a2bcc244db91818ebec76ce5e18', 1),
('Sara', '5d569dfc13001c8b30aa11eeb2a59d22071f3d80', 1),
('Tom', '26d58cf3df0903a2298788b72fced5bca9ea7144', 1);
```

shows the username, and the hash passwords of users. 
But, it does not help me to obtain the passwords, because it seems that the passwords are kept in hash format.

I was going to reset these passwords with new passwords, but the hashing function is not clear. For instance, the hashed passwords could be obtained either from ***md5***, or ***sha1***. Therefore, the replacement would not work.

**My opinion is the code is not enough for selenium test, since I don't have credential. I would like to know your opinion too**

Comment: identify which one it is won't probably really help you. If done right, the hash is made with a salt, that you cannot guess, and anyway, these hash methods are not bijective (you can't unhash it from the hashed value). If you don't have access to the code, that will be hard. By the way, what you are trying to do is very unclear. What is the relation between you not having the credentials and the fact your application would be broken? what are you really trying to do?

Comment: for the selenium task yes, i guess it is broken, if the task was supposed to lo log you in for testing and it doesnt. Does it mean the app does not work? i don't know. By the way i found this: `<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" [...stuff...]<beans:constructor-arg value="sha" />`. I guess you can try with sha then

Comment: What is your question exactly? I'm not sure what you're asking with "Do you verify that it is impossible to run the selenium on this app without credential, although I have access the code?" -- do you mean "how do you verify" or "would you " or ??

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt  I am given the code, to test it with selenium. My opinion is the code is not enough for selenium test, since I don't have credential. I would like to know your opinion!

Comment: Since you suggested you can replace the passwords, you don't only have access to the code, but to the data too, and you can even manipulate it. And in this case, it is very well possible to login. The algorithm is sha1. If these are the actual values in your database, the passwords are, as I mentioned, just the usernames. If you want to reset them, you can simply replace a password in your database with a password from this list (e.g. e2a79383c1347633461eb9fb56cf4972a0155919) and use the corresponding username (e.g. Jake) as the password. Without access to the data, it would indeed be harder.